# Calculating euler characteristic and geodesic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

We have the usual formula for the euler characteristic in differential geometry $$\chi = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{M}d^{2}\sigma g^{1/2}R + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial M}ds k$$ 
where we define the geodesic curvature $k$ by $$k = \pm t^{a}n_{b}\nabla_{a}t^{b}$$

I want to calculate the geodesic curvature for the flat disk, and for a disk with the metric of a hemisphere. I know how to do this easily using cellular homology, where we may conclude that $$\chi(D^{2}) = 1$$
since the higher homology groups vanish due to the disk being contractible. However, how would I calculate this using differential geometry. I don't have much experience at all with doing calculations in differential geometry, so it would be preferable if one could give the details to the calculation.

I understand that the Ricci scalar is trivial for the case of the flat disk, but I read that we may conclude $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b} = -n^{b}$ for this case which I am unsure of how to conclude.

In addition, how would one compute the geodesic curvature for the case of the disk with the hemisphere metric?

It would be preferable if someone could tell me how to compute the geodesic curvature in general as well. The Ricci scalar is rather straightforward to compute given the metric, but I'm unsure of how to handle the tangent and normal vectors $t^{a},n_{b}$.

Thanks!

Comment: geodesic curvature is a term for curves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature

Comment: There is no geodesic curvature $k_g$ for a surface, but there is one for lines drawn on a surface. There is integral curvature for a surface $ \int K dA $

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192320/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you mean the (integral of the) geodesic curvature of the *boundary* circle, either in the flat disk or in the upper hemisphere. In the case of the flat disk, all the curvature of the circle is geodesic curvature, and the integral is $2\pi$. In the case of the upper hemisphere, the boundary circle is a geodesic, and so its geodesic curvature is $0$.

I would recommend you study some undergraduate materials on curves and surfaces before going to all this tensor/GR notation in higher dimensions. For obvious reasons, I recommend [my notes](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf), available in .pdf form.

Comment: Yes I did mean the boundary circle. Sorry if that isn't clear. I took a differential geometry course, but haven't done this stuff in a while.

Could you please explain how you would calculate the curvature given a curve in general? Did you arrive at your conclusion for the flat disk, because the curvature was constant?

And the conclusion was arrived for the case of the hemisphere metric, since the geodesics for $S^{2}$ in general are the great circles?

Comment: How would we conclude that $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b} = -n^{b}$?

Comment: First of all, note that there's index lowering going on, so $t^a$ may be components of the tangent, but $n_b$ are *not* the components of the normal unless you've got a coordinate system that gives rise to orthonormal basis vectors (which we can do in a flat space). Again, I suggest you go back to the elementary viewpoint and understand it, and then interpret the fancy notation.

Comment: I do understand the basic differential geometry, although I have more experience with differential topology, and yes I do understand the abstract index notation as well. In this case, the $t^{a}$ is the tangent vector to the boundary and $n^{a}$ is the outward unit pointing normal that is orthogonal to $t^{a}$ by hypothesis. But yes, you are correct since $n_{b} = g_{ab}n^{a}$, so $n_{b}$ are clearly not the components of the normal

Comment: So, in the case of the disk, compute with a coordinate system (locally defined around the boundary circle) with $\partial/\partial x^1 = t$ and $\partial/\partial x^2 = n$.

Comment: I did the calculation by simply parametrizing the curve in terms of the usual parameter t, and applying the formula given by the geodesic curvature. I did end up getting 1, which agrees with your result. But I'm just wondering if there's a simple way to show the relation $t^{a}\nabla_{a}t^{b} = -n^{b}$ in general? If we denote $t^{a}$ with $t$, and $n^{a}$ with $n$, then is it true in the flat case that, $((t \cdot \nabla)t)\cdot t = 0$ and $((t \cdot \nabla)t)\cdot n = -n$? where we apply a decomposition into the tangential and normal directions?

Comment: This equation is the tensor notation for the covariant derivative $\nabla_t t\cdot n$. $t^i\nabla_i t^j$ is the directional derivative of $t$ in its own direction (i.e., with respect to arclength along the curve), and then we're dotting it with $n$. This is precisely the definition of geodesic curvature. To say that curvature is $1$ is to say that the derivative of $t$ is equal to precisely $n$. I don't know where the negative sign comes from.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing I was wondering about. Is there an obvious way to see the equality between the abstract index notation of the geodesic curvature and the usual notation? i.e. that we have $$\frac{\ddot{\gamma}(t) .(n(t) \times \dot{\gamma}(t))}{|\dot{\gamma}(t)|^3} = t^{a}n_{b}\nabla_{a}t^{b}$$? I see that $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ possibly corresponds to $t^{a}$, and the normal vector is obvious. The cross-product in einstein notation usually corresponds to contraction involving the levi-civita symbol, so I don't see, at first glance, how they are equivalent.

Comment: No, the stuff on the left is extrinsic (in $\Bbb R^3$ only), and depends on the parametrization. The stuff on the right, as I said, is just computing the first Frenet equation $t'\cdot n$ for an arclength parametrization. This makes sense on any Riemannian surface, in fact.

Comment: Right that makes sense. Thanks.